# Complying to DI but not to Dependency inversion principle?

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection

I have found the following code demonstrating Dependency inversion principle. The start with the example of the bad design:

```
// Dependency Inversion Principle - Bad example

class Worker {

    public void work() {

        // ....working

    }

}

class Manager {

    Worker worker;

    public void setWorker(Worker w) {
        worker = w;
    }

    public void manage() {
        worker.work();
    }
}

class SuperWorker {
    public void work() {
        //.... working much more
    }
}
```

Later on, they add the interface etc., I understand that. But I can see that the Worker is injected using the setWorker method. Is this dependency injection?

Comment: No, that's not dependancy injection. It's not even dependancy inversion. Dependancy inversion and dependancy injection are 2 completely seperate concepts. Injecting a dependancy simply means having instances of a dependancy passed in to an instance of a dependant rather than having the dependant create those instances itself. This allows for easy swapping out of dependancy implementations (for instance swapping it with a mock or using a different implementation under different circumstances). Dependancy inversion is about making sure your lower level code does not depend on higher level code.

Comment: And making sure high level code does not depend on low level code. This is usually achieved through the use of interfaces, by having your different layers of abstraction depend on interfaces you can swap out implementations without causing breaking changes.

Comment: I know it is not DIP - as i mentioned, they started with this as an example of bad, coupled design.

Comment: @Thomas Cook but they do pass the Worker in the public method. How does that differ from constructor injection?

Comment: Because manage() is dependant on worker, worker is not injected into manage. So now you've created a dependancy between manage and setWorker. If you want to take the route of having dependancies injected into each method, you wouldn't have the class wide state, you'd simply have class Manager { public void manage(Worker worker) { worker.work() } }

Comment: @ThomasCook When then add the Interface to the solution, do I understand that correctly that basically once the class depends on an interface, whoever implements that interface can be used?

Comment: Exactly. That's the whole point of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is reducing coupling of dependency-dependent by moving knowledge of how to instantiate dependency somewhere else. `Manager` did not have to know how to build the `Worker`, so your example code successfully passed this hot potato to something outside it. It can be branded Dependency Injection. Without a proper framework in place it's a zero sum game though. Someone somewhere will have to know how to build `Worker`.

Dependency Inversion is reducing coupling of dependency-dependent by hiding implementation details of dependency from dependent. `Manager` knows of `Worker`, which is an implementation detail, so it does not comply with Dependency Inversion principle.

Would `Worker` be an interface, I would still not say `Manager` complies with Dependency Inversion principle, because users have to know to `setWorker` before they can ask `Manager` object to `manage`. That is implementation detail as well.

Would `Worker` be an interface *and* would `Manager` use constructor-based injection instead of setter-based, I'd brand it Dependency Inversion principle compliant. Users wouldn't have to know specifics of internal state of `Manager` object to use it.